# Train a neural network when the training has only the derivative of output wrt all inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

There is a scalar function `F` with 1000 inputs. I want to train a model to predict `F` given the inputs. However, in the training dataset, we only know the derivative of `F` with respect to each input, not the value of `F` itself. How I can construct a neural network with this limitation in `tensorflow` or `pytorch`?

Comment: Do you have any hints on the function family of F? Would it make sense to train a network to predict its derivative, and then integrate the weights after training?

Comment: I can design the network with gradient outputs (i.e. 1000 outputs) and train but how can we integrate them to get the function?

Comment: well, assuming you use a linear layer with no activation, and you get a vector w for output `dF(x)/dx[0]`, then  `F(x)[0] = w*x + c[0]`, or in matrix form `F(x) = W*x + c`

Comment: but you need to make some assumptions on F I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`torch.autograd`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html) to compute the gradients, and then use them for the loss. You need:

(a) A trainable `nn.Module` to represent the (unknown) function `F`:

```py
class UnknownF(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, ...):
    # whatever combinations of linear layers and activations and whatever...

  def forward(self, x):
    # x is 1000 dim vector
    y = self.layers(x)
    # y is a _scalar_ output
    return y

model = UnknownF(...)  # instansiate the model of the unknown function
```

(b) Training data:

```
x = torch.randn(n, 1000, requires_grad=True)  # n examples of 1000-dim vectors
dy = torch.randn(n, 1000)  # the corresponding n-dim gradients of the n inputs
```

(c) An optimizer:

```py
opt = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
```

(d) Put it together:

```py
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

for e in range(num_epochs):
  for i in range(n):
    # batch size = 1, pick one example
    x_ = x[i, :]
    dy_ = dy[i, :] 
    opt.zero_grad()
    # predict the unknown output
    y_ = model(x_)
    # compute the gradients of the model using autograd:
    pred_dy_ = autograd.grad(y_, x_, create_graph=True)[0]
    # compute the loss between the model's gradients and the GT ones:
    loss = criterion(pred_dy_, dy_)
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()  # update model's parameters accordingly.
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution. I wonder if this is limited to batch size of 1 or can be extended to general case.

Comment: @Roy since you can only compute gradients of scalar functuons, you can compute the gradients for one sample at a time. However, yoy can do gradient accumulation to have effectively larger batches

Comment: Do you have a link for gradient accumulation, I am not familiar with that.

Comment: @Roy https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-gradient-accumulation/55955

Comment: Do you know how to parallelize this? I have posted a question about this, it would be great if you could provide some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879164/pytorchs-autograd-issue-with-joblib

Comment: @Roy I saw your other question, but I am not familiar with the parallel package you are using.